# Eclipse war export: optimize for a specific server runtime

Tags: java, eclipse, war

In eclipse, when exporting a web project to `war/ear` file there is this option

> "Optimize for a specific server runtime"

[image: optimize for specific server runtime]

What does happen under the hood when this option is selected? Couldn't find an explanation about that so far.

I am running `Eclipse Indigo 3.7`.

Comment: I too would love to know the answer to this.

Comment: I'd like to know what this does as well.  I added a bounty to the question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Eclipse itself doesn't do anything with that option. What happens is dependent on a particular server adapter. Many of the adapters don't do anything with this option either, but they might in the future.

If a server adapter does support export optimization, it has the option of displaying custom options beneath that pop-up list of runtimes, so that's a good cue to use to see if something will actually happen.

For instance, when targeting WebLogic Server, you will see this:

[image]

Comment: Always check your documentation. I have been wondering about what IBM - WAS specific connector would do if I selected "optimize for a specific server runtime" and it happens to do [nothing](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSRTLW_9.5.0/com.ibm.javaee.doc/topics/timpexbinmod.html?lang=en) under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

maybe pre-compiles JSPs - this is the first typical thing to do=) ?

Comment: sure, but I guess this is not runtime dependent, is it?